# Base de datos especifica para cada empresa

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, express

Me dispongo a empezar un proyecto web siguiendo el stack MERN, debido a esto me surgen bastantes dudas ya que MongoDB y Node son nuevos para mi y no tengo mucha experiencia, he buscado por la web pero no he encontrado una respuesta que encaje con mi caso de uso. Os detallo mi problema:

Mi WebApp es un registro de horas, manejo de horas extra, etc. por tanto es necesario separar los registros en una base de datos por cada empresa, la idea del esquema es que el cliente mande una petición a la api y esta a su vez a la bd correspondiente:

[image: Texto]

La idea es que al iniciar sesión, te identifique la empresa que tienes asignada y te conecte a la base de datos de tu empresa, hay que tener en cuenta que yo como superadmin soy el que daría de alta a una cuenta de la empresa y ésta a su vez daría de alta a sus trabajadores.

No se si esto se puede hacer pero en todo caso me ayudaría mucho si pudieseis orientarme o ayudarme.

Muchas gracias de antemano a todos, cualquier duda contactadme.

Comment: Los datos del inicio de sesión en dónde almacenas? En una base de datos diferente a la de cada empresa?

Comment: Lo que buscas se llama multitenancy, por otro lado por favor lee [ask]

Comment: @BetaM , no conocía el concepto de MultiTenancy, ya he empezado a buscar e informarme, en cuanto al como preguntar, me lo leeré para así poder formular mejores preguntar en un futuro. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no tengo una basta experiencia en MERN pero si he logrado hacer un par de cosillas.

En principio no creo que fuese necesario hacer una BD por cada empresa, te recomiendo leer [esto](https://www.tutorialesprogramacionya.com/mongodbya/detalleconcepto.php?punto=3&codigo=3&inicio=0) para que entiendas un poco de lo que explico a continuación

En principio no creo que fuese necesario hacer una BD por cada empresa, en todo caso en la misma BD crea una colección para empresas y otra colección para usuarios , y a estos últimos los "relacionarás" con su empresa correspondiente. Entonces tú como superadmin cargarás datos en la colección **empresas** principalmente, y claramente también en **usuarios** porque tendrías que definir un usuario admin por cada empresa.
Una vez hecho eso en la lógica interna  tendrás que definir que por cada admin de empresa que cargue un nuevo trabajador automáticamente tomará la empresa del admin y la relacionará con la de ese usuario nuevo que el generó.

Por ejemplo: tu crearás la empresa coca-cola en la colección **empresas**  y un usuario  llamado pepito como admin de coca-cola , entonces pepito tendrá dos atributos
nombre: pepito,
tipo:admin,
empresa: coca-cola (esta la traerá de la relación que definiste de la colección usuarios con empresa)
Entonces cuando pepito cree nuevos usuarios trabajador leerá que él es de coca cola por lo tanto al nuevo usuario le pondrá que es de coca cola.
usuario: josé,
tipo:trabajador,
empresa:coca-cola.

Esto a modo de ejemplo, incluso para empresar podrías crear solo una colección usuarios y ahí mismo definir sus atributos tipicos como nombre, email, password etc, y principalmente un atributo empresa y un atributo tipo, para saber si es admin, superadmin, trabajador, etc. Digamos que la cantidad de atributos y colecciones variará según la complejidad de tu proyecto.

te dejo por si hace falta la documentación de mongodb para profundizar [aqui](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/introduction/)

Todo esto de la BD deberás definirlo en node con ayuda de un módulo llamado mongoose y el uso de schemas, te dejo [aqui](https://apuntes.de/nodejs-desarrollo-web/esquemas-en-mongoose/#gsc.tab=0) algo de mongoose y los schemas

Segundo , para el manejo de la api te recomiendo aprender bien nodeJS y el framework expressJS, aprender las 4 peticiones básicas de la api Rest: get, post, put, delete, y luego de ello aprender sobre rutas.
te dejo algo de eso [aqui](https://juanda.gitbooks.io/webapps/content/api/arquitectura-api-rest.html) para que te des una idea

con ello podrás hacer un CRUD todo por "consola" digamos ya que aún no tendrás interface gráfica.

te dejo un video que explica de forma básica como hacer un CRUD básico desde la instalación de express y creación de la api hasta la prueba del funcionamiento con mongodb [aqui](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DqpL5UtJHus)

Luego deberás aprender algo de ReactJs , en un principio entender el concepto de componentes y propiedades , te dejo un enlace de eso [aqui](https://es.reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html)

Para luego poder hacer algo básico visualmente y de manera fácil te recomiendo usar algun framework de CSS para hacerlo más rápido , como por ejemplo , materialize , te dejo algo de materialize [aqui](https://materializecss.com/)

por último deberás aprender como "unir" todo esto, y para resumírtelo te paso un video que explica aproximadamente como unir el frontend con reactJs al backend consumiendo la api que generaste previamente, el video a[aqui](https://youtu.be/204v5QXHlmc)

Comment: Considera que las preguntas basadas en opiniones es mejor no responderlas pues terminan cerradas

Comment: La verdad es que a raíz de conocer el concepto de MultiTenancy que comentó BetaM, ya se que opción escoger y justamente es la que me comentas en esta respuesta. Me encanta lo detallada que es la información que has escrito y te doy las gracias ya que esto desbloquea mi mente por completo y me ayuda mucho a continuar. Muchas gracias

Comment: Nunca es buena idea mezclar los datos de una empresa con otra. Si yo fuera un consumidor de tu aplicación lo primero que te preguntaría es sobre la privacidad de mis datos. Saludos

Comment: @MauricioContreras soy consciente de ello, en este caso el proyecto es meramente educativo por tanto, no es necesario este requerimiento, en cualquier caso si fuese a lanzarla para poder ganar dinero de ello si que me decantaría por no mezclar datos, igualmente muchas gracias por el consejo. Un Saludo